# Appstore IAP Price tiers give wrong prices

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit, skproduct

I've set up everything I need for In-App Purchases for our iOS app, and everything from the technical aspect works. I'm currently testing on Sandbox.

My problem is that the price on the SKProduct (local price in SEK) I get from the SKProductsRequest isn't the correct price from the AppStore price tier list.

Tier 4 should give a price of 45 SEK, but the price I get on the product is 50 SEK. 50 SEK is not a price listed on any tier. This inconsistency seems to appear on all price tiers I've checked.

Other apps using IAP that I've checked have all had prices that are consistent with the price tier list.

I've triple-checked to make sure that I've selected the correct tier on the product and that I'm using the correct productID.

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Edit*
As far as I could tell, the prices on Sandbox used an old price list (I found an old price tier list that matched the wrong prices I got). We ended up not releasing that version, so I'm not sure if the prices were correct in production, though I assume they would be.

Comment: Where did you get the info with the 45 SEK for Tier 4 from? Maybe your source is outdated?

Comment: @PaulSchröder I got that directly from the price tier list on AppStore. There's a link in to it from where you create the IAP products.

Comment: Same issue here. IAP code was working fine for years. The displayed price (amount and currency) comes directly from the SKProduct data. 

Today some user see the expected price (Tier 43), some other users see another price (Tier 39). Coincidently, Tier 39 is 42.99€, which corresponds to the amount of Tier 43 in USD ($42.99 <-> 47.99€).

Looks like some kind of ongoing bug at Apple.

Comment: @romrom I'm not sure that's the same issue I'm having, but that's interesting to know.

Comment: Same issue for me since a few days. All prices are returned for the tier above (i.e. tier 15 => 16), except on simulator. Apple do not respond. Did you find the root cause or a workaround ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case I raised a concern with Apple's Tech Support and they confirmed that the bug is on AppStore Server side and asked to Report it. Please note that I tried an empty StoreKit Demo, in which I observed the same behaviour.

I had to grab a Console log from my device (with App Store profile installed).

Then go to FeedbackAssistant and raise a Bug related to StoreKit, adding app ID, affected product IDs, description of the issue etc. and attaching the log.

Comment: having the same problem and being afraid of releasing the app. Is the Live version showing the correct prices? The TestFlight version returns a wrong price for SKProduct.price (€ 1.09), but showing the right price in Apple Buy-Screen (€ 1.19)

Comment: We have the same issue @d03090, is there any progress in your app?

Comment: @AlpcanYıldız It is working in the Live version of the app. There the right price is shown.